# How a single Autosys job monitors multiple folders for file at a time?

Tags: jobs, autosys

I have task in which there are 3 folders at one location each of one having different files coming in.

Then I want to create an Autosys file watcher job which will monitor 3 folders and if it finds any file in any of the folders then it will move that file to respective folder in another location?

Does anyone have an idea how a single job will monitors multiple folders?

Answer (score 0):

I believe you will need to create a job per file you want to monitor. The File Watch job type will only accept a single file in its `watch_file` attribute.

If you're using Autosys r11, the File Trigger job type will accept wildcards in the `watch_file` attribute, which may be able to help in your situation.